# Insert Spaces in Command Using Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, stmaryrd

I borrowed a predefined command (below), which uses math mode. Within the [[ ]], obviously, it doesn't observe spacing. Is there a way to make the command observe spacing within the [[ ]]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\newcommand{\sem}[2][]{\mbox{$[\!\bf[ #2 ]\!]^{#1}$}}
\begin{document}
\sem{Two words}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question and its answer might be helpful: [Macro for Typesetting Semantic Denotations (Linguistics)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121605/macro-for-typesetting-semantic-denotations-linguistics). Also, `stmaryrd` already defines double bracket delimiters. Unless you want different spacing, why not just use those?

Comment: You can use `\mbox{$[\![ \mbox{\bfseries #2} ]\!]^{#1}$}` instead, may be?

Comment: Are you planning to use this command in text mode or in math mode?

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to use `\bf`. See [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)

Comment: But to answer your question, you can put the arguments inside of `amsmath`'s `\text`.

Comment: Thanks guys! That'll do it. This is text mode, not math mode. Good point about `\bf`, I honestly forgot about that because it hasn't been an issue...yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just close math mode and reopen it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\sem}[2][]{%
  \mbox{$\llbracket$\bfseries #2$\rrbracket^{#1}$}%
}

\begin{document}
Here are \sem{Two words} and here is \sem[1]{One}.
\end{document}
```

[image]